# Geometrical Optics Multiple Reflections Question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, education

Could anyone explain the concept behind and how we arrive at the answer to this question?

What is the value of α for which there are maximum 2 reflections only ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two concepts:

1. The angle of incidence is equal to the angel of reflection.  This also implies that the complement of the angel of incidence is equal to the complement of the angle of reflection.
2. The final outgoing ray must be angled above the horizontal so as to avoid extending down to hit the horizontal mirror again for a total of three reflections.

The first concept allows you to deduce the value of all the angles between mirrors, incoming rays and outgoing rays in terms of $\alpha$

The second tells you that, for example, the ***acute*** angle between the sloping mirror and the final outgoing ray must be less than $60^o$